# Playing Music with pause|play|forward buttons

Tags: android, android-music-player, slidingpanelayout

I'm trying to implement a Sliding Up panel to my android application with a music player just like in Google Play Music. I tried Umano library to implement the sliding up panel.I've done it successfully. But i have no idea how to implement a player with music player,play buttons etc. I've searched every where but could not find a way to do this.

My Layout which includes the sliding up panel

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="60dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.crytal.etunesdev.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Music Player"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
            android:background="@color/button_material_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>



    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

The library I've used - [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/424)

What i expect to do is something like this

[image]

Comment: You can checkout my project https://github.com/protocol10/ASplayer. I have created a simple player for it. You can check it out on google play to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akshay.protocol10.asplayer

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/   try this ..